# Consultar datos desde DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview

Estoy tratando de que en la primer columna del `DataGridView` se ingrese un código, por ejemplo: **001** en la primer celda, **002** en la segunda celda. Quiero que cuando se presione **enter** se carguen en las celdas de las columnas siguientes con los datos correspondientes a ese código desde la consulta a `SQL Server`. A su vez necesito que si el usuario modifica el valor de cantidad del `DataGridView` se muestre el precio de ese producto según la cantidad que haya ingresado.

¿Cómo puedo conseguirlo?

Actualmente, hago esto para cargar el `DataGridView`:

```
private void Query(int idProducto, int indice)
        {
            ConexionSQL sql = new ConexionSQL();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sql.conn))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();//abrimos la conexión
                    String consulta = "SELECT producto, cantidad, precio FROM productoDTG " +
                        "WHERE idProducto = @idProducto";//creamos un string con la consulta a sql
                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(consulta, con);//cremaos un comando al cual le pasamos las variables que serían la consulta y la conexión para que las ejecute
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idProducto", idProducto);
                    ds = new DataSet();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);//este se encarga de inicializar el command
                    da.Fill(ds);//aquí se agergan o actualizan las fila

                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt = ds.Tables[0];

                    if (dt.Rows.Count==1)
                    {
                        dtgClientes.Rows[indice].Cells[1].Value = Convert.ToString(dt(0)(1));
                        dtgClientes.Rows[indice].Cells[2].Value = Convert.ToString(dt(0)(2));
                        dtgClientes.Rows[indice].Cells[3].Value = Convert.ToString(dt(0)(3));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error en los datos.");
                    }

                    con.Close();//cerramos al conexión
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }
```

Y desde este evento intento realizar lo que digo

```
private void dtgClientes_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
            {
                int valor = Convert.ToInt32(dtgClientes.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value);

                Query(valor, e.RowIndex);
                
            }
        }
```

Pero en la línea: `[dtgClientes.Rows[indice].Cells[1].Value = Convert.ToString(dt(0)(1));]` me dice **se espera nombre de un método** justo en donde está el `dt(0)(1)`

¿Alguien tiene idea de cómo lograrlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error ocurre porque debes utilizar `[]` en lugar de `()` para hacer referencia a la posición de `.rows` y `.cells`

```
private void dtgClientes_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
            //                                          |          |      |             |
            //                                          V          V      V             V
            int valor = Convert.ToInt32(dtgClientes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value);
            cargarDT(valor, e.RowIndex);
    }    
}
```

### Actualización

Aunque la pregunta y el código original fueron cambiados, la causa del nuevo error es la misma.
Haces uso de `()` cuando deberías usar `[]`. Pero ten el cuenta que al corregirlo, encontrarás otro error porque falta el `.Rows`.

A continuación el segmento de código con la corrección para este nuevo caso.

```
if (dt.Rows.Count==1)
{
    //                                                            |   | || |
    //                                                            V   V VV V
    dtgClientes.Rows[indice].Cells[1].Value = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0][1]);
    dtgClientes.Rows[indice].Cells[2].Value = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0][2]);
    dtgClientes.Rows[indice].Cells[3].Value = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0][3]);
}
```

Comment: Ah, claro, y en esta línea: `[dtgClientes.Rows[indice].Cells[1].Value = Convert.ToString(dt(0)(1));]` me dice **se espera nombre de un método** justo en donde está el `dt(0)(1)`